# Why is the input field value not showing in the table?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a *dynamic* HTML table using JavaScript, to which you can add first and last names. But when I click on the submit button, it creates empty cells without an input field value.

#### HTML

```html
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="First Name">
<input type="text" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
<input type="button" id ="submit" value="Submit" >

<table border="1" id="table">
    <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### JavaScript

```javascript
let name = document.getElementById("name").value;
let lastname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
let submit = document.getElementById("submit");
let table = document.getElementById("table");

var rowNum = 1;

submit.addEventListener("click" , function(){
  var row = table.insertRow(rowNum);
  var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell0.innerHTML = name;
  cell1.innerHTML = lastname;
  rowNum++;
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the `inputs` value after `submit`, not in the initial load of the `script`, as the values will be just empty string on script's initial load.

You just need to add `name` and `lastname` variables inside the scope of the `click` event listener.

```js
let submit = document.getElementById("submit");
let table = document.getElementById("table");

var rowNum = 1;

submit.addEventListener("click" , function(){
 let name = document.getElementById("name").value;
let lastname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
 var row = table.insertRow(rowNum);
 var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
 var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
 cell0.innerHTML = name;
 cell1.innerHTML = lastname;
 rowNum++;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="First Name">
<input type="text" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
<input type="button" id ="submit" value="Submit" >
    
<table border="1" id="table">
     <tr>
     <th>First Name</th>
     <th>Last Name</th>
     </tr>
</table>
```